# ARC causes a dangling pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

Ok I use arc in my main application but have ported a control which does not use arc .. every thing compiles etc but I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the controls event ...

The event is initiated from Delegate Method

Is there a way to get the pointers text value from the hex code value i.e `Name*` from the `0X00AA0` address ?

And what is the standard way of checking what arc is deallocating?

Comment: when you say "control that doesn't use ARC", is this code public? what does the delegate method look like?  where does the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error happen?

Comment: @interface Base:UITabBarController<UITabBarDeligate>



and I use the event in another ViewController that implements the controll On the ButtonClick Im overriding the custom tabs

Basically I want to reverse engineer the memory address back to the allocated pointer name

Comment: "I use ark in my main application" - ark? You serious?

Comment: Why don't you guys use it

Comment: What he means is that you said "ark" instead of "ARC" which makes you look technically illiterate (regardless of what your actual competency may be).

Comment: lol Midnight oil sickness

Comment: Getting to the point though, ARC can still cause dangling pointers if `unsafe_unretained` pointers are used (they are required for interacting with certain legacy code).

Comment: Yea you right the point Im trying to get at... is it possible through the application runtime to use the analyse tool to see whats being deallocated by ark

Comment: Have you run the static analyzer on all of your code, including the source code of the “control which does not use arc”?  Did you get any warnings?  Did you fix them?

Comment: Yes it have looks good no errors Maybe my problem lies with the view controller class calling the sub-class inheriting from  a base class with the delegate method Ill try some fixes thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the pointers text value from the hex code value i.e Name* from the 0X00AA0 address ?

Try to play around with llvm debugger. After something crashes or at your breakpoint use something like this:

```
expression 0x00aa0
```